# Drag picture into html table

Tags: java, jquery, html

So on the left hand side of this page I will have an html table which already has a function to add rows dynamically. On the right hand side I would like to have a bunch of pictures that can be dragged onto the html table and that will trigger the addRow() function adding a new row into the table containing the id from the picture. Can someone please tell me how to accomplish this?

EDIT: (answer to GrailsDev)

Well I haven't tried it yet because my research wasn't conclusive. I'm sure I want to do something like this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable(); $("#droppable").droppable({ drop: function() { alert('dropped'); } });
```

where the draggable would be the div encasing the images, however, I need to know how to get some information from the picture to put it into that drop function.

Comment: Please include some code, examples, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the basic idea is that you'll want a `tbody` and `thead` in your html, that way it's possible to make `tr` tags in the `tbody` droppable slots while the header will not accept the images being dragged. Then you make the images `draggable` and the `tr` tags in the rows `droppable` elements that accept `img`.

For [this working example in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/uVYmG/3/), I put the ID in row 1, the title tag in as the name, and a copy of the image in as a thumbnail.

Here is the jQuery code to get it running:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#rightcol img').draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });

    var dropProps = {
        accept: "img",
        activeClass: 'active',
        hoverClass: 'hover',
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            console.log(ui);
            var $im = $(ui.draggable);
            var $row = $('<tr />').append(
                $('<td />').html($im.attr('id'))
            ).append(
                $('<td />').html($im.attr('title'))
            ).append(
                $('<td />').append($im.clone().attr('id', null))
            ).droppable(dropProps);
            $(this).after($row);
        }
    };

    $('#leftcol table tbody tr').droppable(dropProps);
});
```